# Angular2 Child Routing

Tags: angular

i have some problem.
let me explain

this is my html code

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" *ngIf="errorMessage">
   <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
   <strong>{{ errorMessage }}</strong>
</div>
<h3 class="page-header">All Unread Report</h3>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>NIK</th>
       <th>Nama</th>
       <th>Topik</th>
       <th>Detail</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of allcomplaint;let i= index">
      <td>{{i+1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.sendername}}</td>
      <td>{{item.topic}}</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success" routerLink="/edit/{{item.id}}">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

what i want is if i click that edit button link it will navigate to other component. but i always get error like this below

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'edit/1' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit/1

this is my route config

```
{ path: 'dashboard_pool', component: DashboardPoolComponent,
  children:[
    { path: 'unread', component: PoolUnreadReportComponent,
      children:[
        {path:'detail/:id', component:PoolComplaintDetailComponent}
      ]
    },
```

how to resolve this? thanks :)

Comment: Can you show the route configuration for `edit` ??

Comment: do you mean my route config? it is in my question. or do you mean the component of edit link? @SameerK

Comment: I guess the URL you are trying is `dashboard_pool/unread/edit/1`, but under `children` of `unread`, i do not see route config for `edit` in your question,  only `detail` exists. May be cos of this you are getting the error..

Comment: I m so sorry sir. that is my bad. sorry sir . thanks for that. u are the best. sorry my bad @SameerK

Comment: Pls dont be sorry :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
// inside PoolUnreadReportComponent.html
<a class="btn btn-success" [routerLink]="['edit',item.id]">Edit</a>

// inside DashboardComponent.html
<a class="btn btn-success" [routerLink]="['unread/edit',item.id]">Edit</a>
```

**Avoid** using manual concatenation of parameters and use an array to pass the values instead (the so called **link parameters array**). Angular takes care of the rest.

Some extra info about routing:

- `../` means that you go one level up in the route tree
- `./` means sybling
- `/` means absolut path, `[routerLink]="['/edit', item.id]"` would be
  root/edit/:id for example

For more info check the [routing docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: same error. Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard_pool/unread/edit/1' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

i dont know wheter my code is fail or not. :(.
thanks for helping sir

Comment: Next thing that could be wrong is that if a component has a children in the routes definition, then it must contain the element <router-outlet> in the html template . So for example DashboardPoolComponent and PoolUnreadReportComponent should have this element in their templates

Answer (score 1):

It's because using `routerLink` like that calls for a **relative path**.

If you want to go to the child, use

```
<a class="btn btn-success" [routerLink]="'edit/' + item.id">Edit</a>
```

Comment: i dont know about that relative path. im new using this angular. but code that you write is still error sir. like mine. not working :)

Comment: Well yes you have to ... Sorry my bad, I didn't think about checking it, I thought you already had it !

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard_pool/unread/edit/1' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

Comment: i dont know sir. must i add something in my child component ts file (PoolComplaintDetailComponent)?. i dont add anything yet just fresh component